# replace Dates with "no answer" and "too early"

Tags: r, date

I am trying to figure out dates in a survey. The survey has 4 phases, baseline, 30days, 60 days, and 90days, and more than 1000rows. The baseline phase is the one that I want to have as a reference in order to check if it was updated the 30,60 & 90days. There is no problem if in 30/60/90days it was updated the column in more than 30/60/90days, if it is has a date is valid.

Two possible answers:

1. **No answer**: This means that from the baseline date if we add 30/60/90days I don't have any date
2. **Too early**: This means that from the baseline date if we add 30/60/90days is too early to respond

At the moment the df looks like this:

| Baseline | Dates_30d | Dates_60d | Dates_90d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 | 2019-07-1 | NA | NA |
| 2019-06-03 | 2019-07-3 | NA | NA |
| 2019-05-20 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2019-07-01 | 2019-08-1 | 2019-09-1 | 2019-10-1 |
| 2019-05-01 | 2019-06-1 | 2019-07-1 | NA |

And what I want is:

| Baseline | Dates_30d | Dates_60d | Dates_90d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 | 2019-07-1 | too early | too early |
| 2019-06-03 | 2019-07-3 | No answer | No answer |
| 2019-05-20 | No answer | No answer | No answer |
| 2019-07-01 | 2019-08-1 | 2019-09-1 | too early |
| 2019-05-01 | 2019-06-1 | 2019-07-1 | No answer |

An explanation:

for the first row: the baseline phase took place on 2019-06-01, the 30_d on 2019-07-01 but for the 60&90days is too early to respond.

for the second row: the baseline phase took place on 2019-06-03, the 30_d on 2019-07-03 but for the 60&90days columns has passed the 60 and 90 days that could be answered for that reason is "No answer".

Comment: I don't understand the difference in treatment between row 1 and row 2. In each, it seem there's a number in Baseline and a date in `Dates_30d` that is 29 days later, but it looks like you want different output in the final columns in each case. Can you explain more, maybe walking through the calculation for a few example rows?

Comment: Sorry, the column of Dates_30 for rows 1 & 2 should be  2019-07-01 and  2019-07-03 respectively.

Comment: Please update your question so the input data and desired results reflect what you expect. And please add some explanation, as I don't understand why some rows' Dates_90d have "too early" and some "No answer" when the inputs seem to have similar conditions.

Comment: Yes, please add explanation. In column 3, row 1 is "too early" and in column 3, row 2 is "No answer", even if it looks like deadline for respondent in row 2 was later than deadline for respondent in row 1 (2019-08-01 for respondent in row 1 and 2019-08-03 for respondent in row 2 I guess). It is really not clear, what is the rule saying when should be "no answer" and when "too early"

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit indication of the reference date it is not possible
to assign the status "no answer" or "too early". For example, if today is
the 8th of November, 2021 and `Dates_90d` column in the data frame is `NA` then it is "no answer", but if today is the 1st of August, 2019 it is "too early".
I took a liberty and chose the 1st of August, 2019 as a reference.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_table("
Baseline  Dates_30d Dates_60d Dates_90d
2019-06-01  2019-07-01 NA  NA
2019-06-03  2019-07-03  NA  NA
2019-05-20  NA  NA  NA
2019-07-01  2019-08-01 2019-09-01   2019-10-01
2019-05-01  2019-06-01  2019-07-01  NA", col_types = "DDDD")


# I put for the sake of the test 
# the date which is relevent to 
# the time frame of the survey.
# in general it should be
# tday <- today()
tday <- ymd("2019-08-01")

early <- function(bl, date, n, tday) {
  
  if(!is.na(date)) 
    r <- as.character(date)
  else if(tday - bl < n)
    r <- "too early"
  else
    r <- "no answer"
   r
}

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(status_30d = early(Baseline, Dates_30d, 30, tday),
         status_60d = early(Baseline, Dates_60d, 60, tday),
         status_90d = early(Baseline, Dates_90d, 90, tday))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  Baseline   Dates_30d  Dates_60d  Dates_90d  status_30d status_60d status_90d
  <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 2019-06-01 2019-07-01 NA         NA         2019-07-01 no answer  too early 
2 2019-06-03 2019-07-03 NA         NA         2019-07-03 too early  too early 
3 2019-05-20 NA         NA         NA         no answer  no answer  too early 
4 2019-07-01 2019-08-01 2019-09-01 2019-10-01 2019-08-01 2019-09-01 2019-10-01
5 2019-05-01 2019-06-01 2019-07-01 NA         2019-06-01 2019-07-01 no answer
```

Comment: The reference date is different each time. So it needs to check each time the baseline date and then update it as "no answer" or "too early".

Comment: Unfortuntely not possible to conclude. E,g, I made a survey on January 1, 2021 and waiting for the follow-up from  the survey participants. I know that by February 1 I need to obtain the feedback, but without knowing what date is it today I cannot judge is it "too early" or "too late". Hence you need to add the column where reference date is added ("today" for each row).